# Why Do I Get Parser Error On Asp.net Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

I'm doing a school project in asp.net, C#, sql and now we need to verify ID so we're using Web Service and i really cant figure out why its not working. so the whole code is a templet its just when I'm doing the connection: Add>Service Reference its telling me I have an error.
the asp.net project's name is WebService.
the .asmx file's name is CheckID.
this is the CheckID.asmx code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CheckId
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CheckId : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        // DEFINE RETURN VALUES
        public enum IDStatus
        {
            NOT_VALID = -2,
            ILLEGAL_INPUT = -1,
            VALID = 1
        };
        [WebMethod]
        public IDStatus Checkid(string idnum)
        {
            // Validate correct input - from 5 to 9 digits
            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(idnum, @"^\d{5,9}$"))
                return IDStatus.ILLEGAL_INPUT;
            // If the number is too short (less than 9 digits, but at least 5) - add leading 0000

            if (idnum.Length < 9)
            {
                while (idnum.Length < 9)
                {
                    idnum = '0' + idnum;
                }
            }
            // Check ID number
            int sumval = 0;
            int curNum;
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                curNum = Convert.ToInt32(idnum[i].ToString());
                curNum *= (i % 2) + 1;
                if (curNum > 9)
                    curNum -= 9;
                sumval += curNum;
            }
            if (sumval % 10 == 0)
                return IDStatus.VALID;
            else
                return IDStatus.NOT_VALID;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the line 1 code:
`<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="CheckID.asmx.cs" Class="WebService.CheckID" %>`

[this is the error the visual studio shows me and I really can't understand why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYXRZ.png)

I've really tried making a new web service, renaming everything I can, doing almost every possible thing and I still can't figure out the problem...

Comment: I have to ask. Are you required to use this old, irrelevant technology in school?

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive, that means CheckID and CheckId are not the same, notice the upper and lower case 'd' in each.

Notice in your C# code behind, the class is called CheckId while in your asmx file you have the CodeBehind and Class attributes set as CheckID.

For your issue, try replacing this

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="CheckID.asmx.cs" Class="WebService.CheckID" %>
```

with this,

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="CheckId.asmx.cs" Class="WebService.CheckId" %>
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work..